# LM358 differential voltage and amplifier circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, current

I designed a circuit that's rather common:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOS8W1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And I have a problem. I have got few LM358s, some from ST, some from other companies. (I tested LMV358 also - it puts ~5 V as V_OUT_FINAL).
I made a designed circuit and already put every one of those LM358s in it and none works the way I want them to do. I always get a constant error of 1-3 V as V_OUT_FINAL. I also get wrong result as V_OUT_1 (because it's around 0,5-1 V).
I don't know what's wrong. The values in my real project are wrong in terms to the designed and simulated. I simulated it on many tools already and all give me results like those from attached circuit.

V_IN_1 = 12 V, V_IN_2 ~ 12 V (little less than 12V).
V_OUT_1 = few mV.
V_OUT_FINAL ~ 3 V.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this circuit?

Comment: The input voltage (12V) far exceeds the rail voltage (5V), it makes sense is not gonna work. The OA1 output and OA2 input are directly connected.

Comment: First I want to get a differential voltage, which will be a difference of V_IN_1 and V_IN_2. Second, I want to amplify this value so I can measure it with ADC.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I know it exceeds, but the values going into OA1 are within range of 0-5 V (it's ~4 V actually). I tested the circuit with 5 V of voltage on Sense_Res and it neither worked.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič What's wrong about the OA1 output and OA2 input directly connected? It should work.

Comment: If you expect a gain of >1 from first stage then you're wrong, because the net voltage gain of the 1st stage is 100k / 390k = 0.26 . Please note that any opamp-based voltage amplifiers should not have voltage gain values lower than 1. If you put R1=R2=390k and R3=R4=100k then the net gain will be 4. You should also consider the offset error of LM358 because it directly affects the accuracy of the measurement.

Comment: The datasheet allows only +3,5V input with +5V supply. More => no quarantee of proper function. 2mV offset error of  the second opamp is amplified to nearly 1V. Add to it the error from the first stage, which is also amplified. Have you checked is your system stable? The gain is quite high. @jramsay42 This is an attempt to measure the load current and get the result as a voltage against the ground and scaled for easy observation for example via a DAC.

Comment: I see a more fundamental issue as well, when no current flows through the sense resistor you want the voltages V_IN_12 and N_IN_22 to be equal, agree? **This can never happen** because then V_OUT_1 would need to become 0 V. It cannot do that because the opamp has ground and 5 V as supply. Like this it will need a negative supply. An opamp cannot pull it's output properly to ground when the negative supply is also ground. At the moment there's no "headroom" for the opamp to work with.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'll assure it will not be equal.

Comment: @RohatKılıç - I see. I did some test with Vcc = 12 V and R1=R2=R3=R4 = 100k and it seemed a lot better. I had to add 10k resistor from V_OUT_1 to GND so it didn't give me big, wrong result.

Comment: NikoValaday @Bimpelrekkie is right. See my detailed answer below. You have to either use a bigger sense resistor, or change the first op amp. Either way, that opamp needs a dual supply. LMV358 has worse low output swing than LM358.

Comment: Can you not use a proper high side current amplifier or use a low side shunt R.? Is the load regulated from the high side or the low side? It is impossible to design anything without these kind of specs

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly a result of *input offset voltage* of OA2. In the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosbt3j/snosbt3j.pdf), page 7, it's quoted to be typically 2mV, but can be as bad as 7mV. In my experience, I have frequently seen this value closer to 4mV, in spite of the claim that this figure is typically 2mV, but I may have just been unlucky, as may have you.

The closed-loop gain of an amplifier employing the LM358 (which is \$1+\frac{R_6}{R_5}=391\$ in your case, for OA2) is applied not only to your explicit input from OA1, but also to this input offset voltage.

Typically, then, with input offset voltage \$V_{OFS}=2mV\$, and a gain of 391, what you actually see at the output will be \$391 \times V_{OFS} \approx 0.8V\$ different (higher or lower, depending on the sign of the \$V_{OFS}\$) from what you expect.

There will also be a similar offset due to OA1, with closed-loop gain of about \$\frac{1}{4}\$. OA1's output can therefore be offset by about 0.5mV, contributing an further \$391 \times 0.5mV \approx 0.2V\$ error overall.

This is not so much a problem in AC amplifiers (like audio), where multiple gain stages can by cascaded, and all AC coupled with a capacitor to remove this "parasitic" DC offset at each stage, since all you are interested in is AC amplitude. However, when you're concerned with absolute DC potential, as you are, input offset voltage is a royal pain in the neck.

There are three things you can do, that I can think of.

Your first option is use a better op-amp. There are devices which are designed to have low input offset voltage, such as the [OPA391](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2391.pdf), which has \$V_{OFS}=60\mu V\$, 100 times better than the LM358. Also such devices also generally have better offset drift, which I'll explain later.

Secondly, you can use a chopper-stabilised op-amp, like the [AD8628](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8628-8629-8630.pdf) or [TLC2652](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc2652.pdf), which auto-zeroes itself periodically, to cancel input offsets, achieving 1μV input offset voltage. There's a price though (both in dollars and performance), which is output noise due to internal switching.

Lastly, you can cancel the inherent offset yourself, by adding your own. Some op-amp ICs have pins specifically for this purpose, often called "offset null" or "balance". Even the legendary not-recommended-for-*any*-design-thank-you-for-your-service-but-you're-fired [741](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) has this feature. In your case, though, the LM358 doesn't, so you'll have to roll your own.

Since the overall offset at the output is potentially so great, it's possible for OA2 to saturate against one or the other supply rail, which would invalidate the output, and also any correction you apply following it. You must introduce a DIY offset at the *input* to OA1, or OA2, but not the output of OA2, where it's already too late.

Importantly, there is another reason to introduce your own offset, which has to do with the op-amp's inability to produce an output close to 0V. The datasheet claims that the LM358's output can fall to 5mV typically, but that minimum maybe as high as 20mV. Therefore, neither OA1 or OA2 should be asked to output under 20mV. I would recommend not asking for under 50mV, to be safe.

This places another constraint on where offset correction should be applied; it can only be at the input of OA1, since that op-amp also has this output constraint. Now let's consider the effect that a 50mV minimum output (corresponding to 0A through the sense resistor) from OA1 would have at the output of OA2. That output would be \$391 \times 50mV = 19V\$. OA2 simply can't do that, with a gain of 391, it would immediately saturate.

It seems that with this design, you must not only apply an offset at the input of OA1, to keep its output above 50mV, but you must also apply *another* offset at the input of OA2 to compensate for both the first offset, *and* for OA2's own flawed behaviour! Not trivial.

The last issue that I can see is that OA2 suffers from the same minimum output constraint, meaning that OA2's output must be *above* 0V (+50mV) to represent 0A through the sense resistor. That's not a huge problem, since you can correct for that offset in software.

Of course, the problem of the impossible 0V output can be instantly solved by giving your op-amps a negative supply, say -1V, or -5V. In fact, by using an *inverting* amplifier configuration, (and swapping the inputs to the first differential stage), it's simple to integrate *summing* of an offset potential at it's input. Such a design might look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiZnPP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

VR1 produces a potential between +5V and -5V, which is added to the output. You'll notice that gain via that path is \$-\frac{390k}{390k}=-1\$. The idea is to set current in the load to 0A, and adjust VR1 until you see 50mV at the output of OA2. This offset must be subtracted in software.

Note that OA2 has 0V for its lower supply, which prohibits the op-amp from producing a negative output which could damage your ADC. Since its inverting input (node S) is a virtual ground, we don't violate input voltage range constraints, and this stage should be fine with the negative output of OA1.

I also recommend the addition of C1 to attenuate above 500Hz or so, since this is not a particularly good op-amp for noise, and such a large feedback resistance doesn't help either. I chose to increase R6 because of the impedance of VR1, which shouldn't be so small as to draw excessive supply current. Also, a larger R5 is less strain on OA1's output.

If you don't have a negative supply, and don't want to make one, then you must approach the problem differently. As I alluded to, OA1's output can't get below +20mV, which corresponds to a load current of 16A! So you absolutely *must* lift the output of OA1 by 20mV at least, to get any meaningful output from OA1. Then deal with that offset later.

I've only given this minimal thought, so others here are sure to have better ideas, but I suggest raising the operating point of the two op-amps in the above design, by creating a "fake" ground using another op-amp, in the blue box:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzOJvb.png)</sup>

It may seem that we've also shifted up the output from OA2 by 1V, since, that's the new "center", correspnoding to 0A, but don't forget, VR1 (and its periphery) allows you to subtract 1V (or any amount, up or down) from the output, so you can still adjust VR1 to obtain a signal of +20mV corresponding to 0A sensed current, rising to a maximum of about 4V (for the LM358), as that current rises.

I set the VR1 in the simulation above to achieve 40mV or so when load current is zero. Here's a plot of the variation of \$V_{OUT}\$ as current is swept from 0 to 8A:

[image]

---

Drift of input offset voltage with temperature is another concern, although not as severe. The LM358 has a drift of 7μV per °C change in temperature. So even if you do manage to correct the offset at 25°C, you can expect it to be different (above or below) by about \$7 \times 25 = 175\mu V\$ at 0°C or 50°C, for example. That would correspond to an output fluctuation of \$175\mu V \times 391 = 70mV\$. Again, different op-amp models have different drift coefficients, so you may have to search around for a more suitable device.

Answer (score 0):

1. First **disconnect** second stage input from first stage output.
2. **Biasing (DC) of Pin 2 and Pin 3**. Pin3 is held at approximately 1.4 volt and Pin 2 at about 12 volts. Your inputs at those Pins have to be of level which would not require any amplifier circuit. A resistor from Pin2 to ground is required to bias the pin properly. Else connect it to input through a series resistance of 10K. Use coupling capacitors to avoid disruption of dc condition of pins.
3. **Feed back**. Pin 2 is fed back through 100K (R4). The present configuration gives stage gain of (R4/R2 = 0.25). R2 value (input impedance) should be (for example) 10K for gain of 10.
4. Preferably use  Variable Resistor (one for a pair) for setting DC conditions of Pins. Later on, you can use fixed value resistance.
5. After fixing stage 1 check stage 2 dc conditions, connect stage 1 output to stage 2 through a coupling capacitor and check.

Answer (score 0):

OA1 is a differential amplifier. It outputs the voltage difference across the sense resistor (multiplied with any gain). This voltage is very small, close to zero. So the output is close to zero. The LM358 output can come close to zero (5mV typical, 20mV max), but will show an error in this application where the voltage across the sense resistor is too small (30mV, which becomes 7.5mV with an opamp gain set at 0.25).

So, either have a dual supply for the OA1, or feed a positive offset voltage at R3, instead of connecting it to ground. [An offset will make things rather complicated for OA2 and the ADC in this application.] Once V_out_1 can approach 0V, the V_out_final will hopefully also fall into range.

The OA1 gain needs to be set at 0.25, due to the 12V supply of the load and the 5V supply of OA1. This brings the signal into range for OA1. If you can supply OA1 with ±12V, you can potentially set a gain of 1. The output of OA1 will then go to 30mV. The gain on OA2 can then be reduced a bit. Remember that due to input offset errors (5mV max), the LM358 may not be a good opamp in this application. One can try increasing the value of the sense resistor, if possible, to work around this. In this circuit (5 m ohm sense resistor), an OP07 would be a better choice for OA1 (which requires a dual supply anyway).

Remember to use 5V for OA2, so that the ADC voltage is not accidentally exceeded. Or, have input voltage protection for the ADC.

An entirely different approach would be to have the ±5V sitting on the +12V (just after the sense resistor, so that becomes ground for the opamps and ADC) and run everything there. The output of the ADC can be taken out with an optocoupler if there is additional circuitry. One will then not even require a differential amplifier, just one opamp in normal configuration will suffice and then feed it to ADC. This way, there will not even be any limitation of the 12V (any voltage, even much higher can be used).

An alternate approach:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8sVsD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>